# Product of posets with Hausdorff interval topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory, posets

Given a poset $(P,\leq)$ the *interval topology* on $P$ is generated by
$$\{P\setminus\downarrow x : x\in P\} \cup \{P\setminus\uparrow x : x\in P\},$$
where $\downarrow x = \{y\in P: y\leq x\}$ and $\uparrow x = \{y\in P: y\geq x\}$.

Let $\{P_i : i\in I\}$ be a family of posets such that the interval topology of each $P_i$ is Hausdorff. Is the interval topology of $\prod_{i\in I} P_i$ also Hausdorff? (We say that $(x_i)_{i\in I} \leq (y_i)_{i\in I}$ in $\prod_{i\in I} P_i$ if and only if $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i\in I$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement in the answer by Dominic that the interval topology of the product poset is the product topology of the interval topologies is incorrect. The argument that the product topology contains the interval topology is correct, but the one for the opposite containment is not, as shown in this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/281902/2926).

And in fact the interval topology for $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is *not* Hausdorff, because as shown in the linked answer, every basic open $U$ in the interval topology contains a "northwest quadrant", i.e., a subset of the form $NW_{a b} = \{(x, y): x < a\; \text{and}\; y > b\}$, and the intersection of two northwest quadrants is always nonempty because $NW_{a b} \cap NW_{a' b'} = NW_{\min(a, a'), \max(b, b')}$.

Comment: But why is every subbasic set of the product topology $\tau_p$ open in the interval topology (see my (non-)answer, starting from "Conversely")

Comment: My linked answer says that subbasis elements like $\pi^{-1}(U)$ are *not* open in the interval topology, because $\pi_1^{-1}(U)$ is too small to contain any union of a northwest quadrant and a southeast quadrant (and any basic in the interval topology contains such a union). In brief, your displayed formula for $U$ is incorrect. Try drawing a picture of a $P \setminus (\uparrow (x, y))$, which looks like a complement of a northeast quadrant (i.e., looks like a "thick L-shape"), and you should see this easily.

Comment: That's right, thanks for the picture!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **Yes**, because the product topology of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff again, and because the product topology of the interval topologies of a family of posets equals the interval topology of the product:

**Lemma.** The interval topology $\tau_i = \tau_{\textrm{int}}(\prod_{i\in I}P_i))$ on $P=\prod_{i\in I} P_i$ equals the product topology $\tau_p$ of the topological spaces $(P_i, \tau_{\textrm{int}}(P_i))$.

*Proof*. Take a subbasic element of $U\in\tau_i$ and show that it is a member of $\tau_p$. W.l.o.g. we let $U = P\setminus (\uparrow(x_i)_{i\in I})$ where $x_i\in P_i$. Note that $\uparrow(x_i)_{i\in I}$ is a product of closed sets in the spaces $(P_i, \tau_{\textrm{int}}(P_i))$, therefore it is closed in the product topology, so $U\in \tau_p$. Conversely, let $U = \pi_i^{-1}(U_j)$ be subbasic in $\tau_p$ where $\pi_j: P\to P_j$ is the projection map and $U_j = P_j\setminus \uparrow x^*$ for some $x^*\in P_j$. Then $$U = \bigcup \{P\setminus (\uparrow (z_i)_{i\in I}): (z_i)_{i\in I} \in P \text{ and } z_j =x^*\}.$$
So $U\in\tau_i$. QED.